# Unexpected app "Admin Alert" running on my machine

Tags: applications, security, malware

All of a sudden I noticed an application called "Admin Alert" in my dock.

This is a work computer, I'm wondering if this is some sort of "spyware" that our lovely IT department has installed on my machine.  I can't find any information about it online.

[image: Link]

(OSX 10.8)

Answer (score 5):

Admin Alert is related to Dell [KACE](http://www.kace.com), an "appliance-based approach to systems management", and the admin alert icon appearing in the dock is apparently [a bug](http://www.itninja.com/question/admin-alert-poping-on-apple-systems).